# access documents directory on physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, file, documentsdirectory

I created some text files contains the logs of my app but I can't access those files from my physical device I can only access them on the simulator using this path :
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

is there a way to view the documents directory associated to my app on my physical device?

Comment: Using Xcode you can transfer the app bundle off your phone from the devices window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps.

[image]

Select `Add Additional Simulators`. From devices tab select your application and download container. You'll find all details.

[image]